# Functional inequality with complex variables

Tags: linear-algebra, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

I am interested in considering a function $C(\tau)$ of the complex variable $\tau = t + i\eta$ such that

1. $C(\tau)$ is analytic for $\Re(\tau)=t>t_0\ge0$
2. $\exists$ a constant $C_0$ and a function $B(\eta)$, positive and integrable for $-\infty<\eta=\Im(\tau)<\infty$ s.t.
   $$
   \left\lvert C(\tau) - \frac{C_0}{\tau} \right\rvert \le B(\eta) \quad \forall \,\,t>t_0 \,.
   $$

Is it sufficient to require $C(\tau)$ to decay faster than $1/\tau$ for the last condition to be satisfied? For instance, does $C(\tau) = e^{-\tau}$ work? My intuitive answer is affirmative, yet I do not know how to prove it. Thanks to anyone willing to help!